# Removing time from date. and keeping the DATE type

Tags: java, android, string, date

I've a date object that returns a calendar.getTime() date.

However, this date is formatted like this:

```
("dd/MM/time/yyyy")
```

1. i want to get rid of that time and still keep the date as a date
   since I need the DATE type for the rest of my application to run
   correctly.  I want it to show as

   ("dd/MM/yyy")
2. how can I do this? the other answers I have seen all require you to
   change it to a string.  is it possible to put it to as string and
   then back to a date with no time?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: If you can possibly use Joda Time, I'd suggest using a `LocalDate` - that way it's really obvious what the value is meant to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dateobject always has a timepart. So you can not have a date without timepart. you only can set the timepart to zero:

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

If you only what to convert it to a `String` you can use SimpleDateFormat:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
    String s = df.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.  I managed to use it this way. I just realized i only need to display is as a string and program with it as a date since no one really looks at the DATE version anyways.  Thank you for answering my question so clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `DateFormat` class, like this:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 01, 30);
DateFormat df = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(this); 
String date = df.format(calendar.getTime());
```

---

```
getDateFormat(Context)
```

this return formatters defined by the system's locale. (It's god if you want support multi date formats (eg us, de)